# how to iterate through a particular part of an object

Tags: php

I have an object which looks like this

```
zen_categories_ul_generator Object
(
[root_category_id] => 0
[max_level] => 6
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [19] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Brushes
                        [count] => 0
                    )

                [29] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Clips
                        [count] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Combs
                        [count] => 0
                    )

                [27] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Jewellery
                        [count] => 0
                    )
             )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [57] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Testing
                        [count] => 0
                    )
             )
```

And I want to loop through all the information at the level $this->data[0], I'm using

```
       foreach($this->data[0] as $category_id => $category) {
            $result .= $category_id.' - '.$category['name'];
        }
       return $result;
```

but this will just the last item in the array. so in this case it would only have 27 - Jewellery but none of the other array item would be returned.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

NB I only need to loop through the data[0] - not data[1] as well!

EDIT - here's a paste bin with a more code to make easier to understand what I'm trying to do and how I'm doing it. Any help gratefully received

http://pastebin.com/Vrw9f7Xh

Comment: `.=` is the concatenation operator. this would be building `foo-barbaz-quxetc-etc`. If you're only getting ONE of the array elements in your new string, then you're doing something wrong and this code isn't what you're running on your end.

Comment: yeah I know it the concatenation operator. I am getting only one array element and this is the code I'm using :(

Answer (score -1):

Question:
Ok, so you want to loop through all the information $this->data[0], to render a menu.

Actually, you were pretty close to the solution, yourself.
The line used for rendering the product items, is:

`$result .= '<a href="' . $category_id . '">'.$category['name'] . '</a> (' . $category['count'] . ')';`

The following is working example, which works standalone.
You might save it as `menu.php` and test it.
I had to comment the zen_* function out, but i think the relevant part is the rendering, right?

```
class zen_categories_ul_generator
{
    function setTestData($data) { $this->data = $data; }

    function buildMenu() {
        $result = '';
        // removed home link, unchanged and not important in this example

        // submenu
        $result .= '<li class="submenu">';

            $result .= '<a href="#">Products</a>';
            $count = 0;
            foreach($this->data[0] as $category_id => $category) {
                $count++;
                $result .= '<ul class="level2">';
                    $result .= '<li class="submenu">';
                        //$result .= '<a href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'cPath=' . $category_id) . '">'.$category['name'].'</a>'.$count;

                        $result .= '<a href="' . $category_id . '">'.$category['name'] . '</a> (' . $category['count'] . ')';


                    $result .= '</li>';
                $result .= '</ul>';
            }

        $result .= '</li> Items:' . $count;

        return $result;
    }

}

$object = new zen_categories_ul_generator;

// ok, lets add your example data from outside to the object, in order to test the rendering
$data = array(
            0 => array(
                    19 => array('name' => 'Brushes',   'count' => 5),
                    29 => array('name' => 'Clips',     'count' => 2),
                    2  => array('name' => 'Combs',     'count' => 1),
                    27 => array('name' => 'Jewellery', 'count' => 3)
                 )
            );

$object->setTestData($data);

// render the menu
echo $object->buildMenu();
```

**Result**

[image]

Count is the number of iterations = the number of Products in a Category.

And the counter behind the product name is from the array, the key "count".

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. I was trying think of how to explain better and I can only think to show you more code would be easy. Can I show you this http://pastebin.com/Vrw9f7Xh   ----   The result of the buildMenu function only seems to have caught the last item in the array

Comment: Ok, i'm taking a look. First thing: you might remove $davesArray (line 27 and 30). that's just wasting memory by duplicating the data. Your usage of `$this->data` is correct. I will update my answer with the menu rendering part.